# Toolbaritem in ToolBar not Firing when click

Tags: xamarin.forms

My code is as below. I dont know if the Command is implemented correctly for the ToolbarItem. There is no error in compiling. When the baritem is clicked, nothing happen.

```
--- Xaml

<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
            xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:SembIWIS.View"  
            BackgroundColor="White"
            Title="Repair and Service"          
            x:Class="MyMainMenu">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="itemIcon1" Command="{Binding Item1Command}"  Priority="0" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary" Icon="itemIcon2" Priority="1" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>   

    <local:Product>
    </local:Product>

    <local:Service>
    </local:Service>   

</TabbedPage>


--------- Code Behind:

public partial class MyMainMenu : TabbedPage
    {
        public ICommand Item1Command { get; private set; }

        public MyMainMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = this;

            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);   
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {

          this.Item1Command = new Command((sender) =>
          {
               Navigation.PushAsync(new UpdateProduct());
          });


}
```

Comment: You've not set the binding context for your view, so the `Command="{Binding Item1Command}"` is binding to nothing.  A short-term workaround is to set the binding context in the `MyMainMenu` constructor: `BindingContext = this;`, although you might want to investigate the MVVM pattern and move your ViewModel to a separate class that knows nothing about the UI.

Comment: This is done on the same page. Can you kindly show me how and where to add the Binding context.

Comment: I updated my comment to explain (I prematurely hit enter).

Comment: @Damian I had added the BindingContext = this in the above code. Somehow, it still not working. Did i miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I gather that you have forgotten to add the `BindingContext`. While you did add it right now, the timing is wrong. You need to execute the `Init();` method before you set the `BindingContext`.

When the `BindingContext` is set, at that point everything is wired up and any change you make will not be picked up, unless you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly. Anyhow, for this problem, adapt your code to this:

```
public MyMainMenu()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);   
    Init();

    BindingContext = this;
}
```

In regard to your question on performance and unit tests in the comment:

There is no performance difference because whichever MVVM framework you will use will execute this very same code only it will do it for you automatically. If anything, the MVVM framework will probably be a tad slower because it will probably resolve your ViewModels with reflection or something similar. If you want to do unit tests you will have to split your code into a separate ViewModel and set that as your BindingContext. For example have a look at this [blog post](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/beauty-and-the-beast-use-mvvm-to-unleash-inner-beauty/) on using FreshMvvm with separate Views and ViewModels.

Comment: just a thought. Comparing this approach and the Mvvm Binding for command, which is easier for unit test? is there any performance differences?